# In the sentence "As a father,". What's the purpose of each of the following parts listed in the description?

Tags: parts-of-speech, functions

In the phrase:

> As a father, ...

what are the functions of the "as a" part and the "father" part?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more natural to split this [[As] [a father]].  This is a prepositional phrase.

"As" is a preposition. In this context, it means "In the role of".

"a father" is a noun phrase functioning as the object of the preposition. It is headed by the noun "father" with the determiner "a" (indicating a single undetermined father)

Comment: Why would someone say, as a father though?

Comment: That wasn't the question that the OP asked.  But I think I've answered it.  "As" means "in the role of"